# call function When Submit is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Hello guy's im trying to call a Function But after i Click on Submit but there is no ID for the submit 
here what i got :

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Continue" onclick="return validateFrm();" class="btn primary-btn btn-ctnue row alignCenter" autocomplete="off">
```

so i want it to be like this for example  :

if Submit Clicked then Run this :
 `function example()
 {    alert('Yay!'); )`

Anyidea How to do it on JavaScript/Jquery

Ps: There a lot of Submit so i want this specific Submit

Comment: What do you mean by 'no id for submit'

Comment: Java !== JavaScript, and why the `tampermonkey` tag?

Comment: Look At the Html there no id for it to call it so how can i Call it then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the submit button using CSS selector `input[name=save]`
2. Add listener to fire on `click` event and pass the function to execute.

```
document.querySelector("input[name=save]").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert('Yay!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="submit-btn">SUBMIT</button> //html file

const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');

  function showAlert() {
  alert ('YAY!');
}
showAlert();

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', showAlert);
```

Comment: THX for help mate